# How do I find the horizontal and vertical asymptote of $\frac{\sqrt[3]x+1}{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}$?

Tags: calculus

I had this question in my quiz and I don't know how to answer it.

For the vertical asymptote, I just guessed $\mathbb{Z}$ because those are the values that will make the denominator 0.

I don't even have any idea how to get the horizontal asymptote of this since there's a GIF involved.

Any help/tips would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the image of the expression in denominator $\;x-\left\lfloor\,x\,\right\rfloor\,$ is $\;\left[0,\,1\right).\,$
Whenever $\,x\,$ is *integer*, we have zero in denominator, i.e. fraction $\,\dfrac{\sqrt[3]x+1}{x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor}\,$ has *vertical asymptote* at *every integer point* $\,x=n\in\mathbb{N}.\,$
On the other hand, enumerator is unbounded in $\,\mathbb R,\,$ so that $\displaystyle\,\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[3]x+1=\infty.\,$
Since dividing by denominator can only *increase* magnitude of enumerator (because the value of denominator is always positive and less than $1$), we conclude that $\,f(x)\,$ has *no vertical asymptotes*.